# Flexbox allways changes the site when i move it

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i got a problem with my code. Everytime i move my page the text is on a completly other position and overlows the most of the time. i am pretty new to coding and i really dont know how to fix it at all.

This is my HTMl data.

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: url('./pics-txt/group/Need2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.filter {
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item {
  border: solid 0px;
  position: relative;
  left: 34%;
  top: 0%;
  padding: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 90%;
}

#text {
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  padding: 1%;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 180%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:70%) {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta hrrp-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test-txt.css">
  <title>Tomorrow x Together</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="filter"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class='item'>MOA</div>
    <div class="item">Member</div>
    <div class="item">Big Hit</div>
    <h1 id="text">Tomorrow x Together</h1>
  </div>

  </video>
</body>
```

i really dont know how to fix it. i also tried to just dont use a flexbox. but i think my Knowledges for that arent good enough xD
i also tried to vary between flex-directions, flex-wraps between different width, heights. to work with and without a div.
I did everything for me possible.

Comment: A few things in your code don't make sense and others could be done better. But the bigger problem with your question is you haven't specified what's the desired outcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I see it is a mix of position, z-index, flex, percentages, etc. It is difficult to find out what the question is. It seems you want to center a box but I'm not sure. If this is the case, try this as starting point.

But again, to help you out please give some extra info about the required layout.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-image: url('./pics-txt/group/Need2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.view {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(2px);
}
.center-container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto; /* center in middle */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .center-container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.item {
  width: 33.333%;
  padding: 2%;
  /* z-index: 2; */
  color: white;
  font-size: 90%;
}
#text {
  padding: 1%;
  /* z-index: 2; */
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 180%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="view">
    <div class="center-container">
      <div class="container">
        <div class='item'>MOA</div>
        <div class="item">Member</div>
        <div class="item">Big Hit</div>
      </div>
      <h1 id="text">Tomorrow x Together</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```